# I am stuck with this javascript/jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/

So, here is the code from the jsfiddle.net

```
  $(".scroll").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //calculate destination place
     var dest=0;
     if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
          dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
     }else{
          dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
     }
     //go to destination
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
   });
```

Here is the problem, on the JSFiddle, the code works fine without any problems. But when I try and plugging it into my text editor and run it, the developer tools gave a warning stating that the "top" is undefined--yet it works perfectly fine in JSFiddle.

Anyone know why so?

::EDIT:: Here is what's in the

```
    <head>
     <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
     <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

      <title>M Y | Portfolio</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
      <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">

       <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
      <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
```

Comment: Have you checked that **every** variable in your code has the expected value? If not - why haven't you?

Comment: I think your code is fine, have you added correct version of jquery ?

Comment: Yup, it's been directly copied and pasted.

Comment: For me no warning is coming, please try to add this jquery -
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @PrabhatJain Still getting the errors :/

Comment: You'll get that error if no elements are matched. Do some debugging, like `console.log(this.hash, $(this.hash).length);`

Comment: Just copy paste the entire code in your text editor and run it add proper jquery version, I am sure no warning will come, as it is not coming for us also.

Comment: @cookiemonster the console.log came back as "undefined 0". Hmmm, I am confused now. I don't know how it's working in JSFiddle, yet receive errors when I try to implement it.

Comment: Hey @PrabhatJain, I re-pasted the entire code (HTML, JS) and no longer get that error. Now, I am getting the "$ is not defined" error.

Comment: You have clearly not added the jquery, just copy paste this-
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

in the head part of your page

Comment: @Prabhatjain I forgot to mention that your source that you have provided was already implemented while getting the error.

Comment: I copied the whole HTML page, and re-pasted. Now I am back to "Cannot read property "top" of undefined" error.

Comment: can you provide the mark up of your `<head>` portion???

Comment: @Kiranramchandran Sure, I updated it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clicking the link that throws the **"top" is undefined"** error, inspect it and check if its href attribute is defined and not empty.